# Search Inside LDAP Server

Tags: ldap, openldap

I was wondering if someone know, when i search an entity over the Ldap server, would I get also it's sub folders and the data inside. for example I have the following:

> *dn:EPC-SubscriberGroupId=AllInOne, EPC-SubscriberGroupsName=EPC-SubscriberGroups,
>   applicationName=EPC-EpcNode, nodeName=jambala changetype:add
>   objectClass: EPC-SubscriberGroup EPC-SubscriberGroupDescription:Voice
>   and Data flat rate EPC-SubscribedServices:PeerToPeer
>   EPC-SubscribedServices:Skype EPC-SubscribedServices:Chat
>
> dn:EPC-Name=EPC-SubscriberQualification,
>   EPC-SubscriberGroupId=AllInOne,
>   EPC-SubscriberGroupsName=EPC-SubscriberGroups,
>   applicationName=EPC-EpcNode,nodeName=jambala changetype:add
>   objectClass: EPC-SubscriberQualification
>   EPC-SubscriberQualificationData:QosProfileId:10000*

So if I will set a query that will try to fetch the entity Epc-SubscriberGroup of SubscriberGroupAllInOne, I will also retrieve the sub folder ( object ) EPC-SubscriberQualification

Hope it's clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get the entry or entries that match the search filter depending on what's in the search filter and what scope you specified for the search. You will get the attributes that you ask for. You will not get subentries.